# Continuity of the limit of a function

Tags: real-analysis

I am having a hard time getting a foothold on this question.  I feel like discontinuity must occur at 0, but I cannot get to a proof.  The question is below:

Suppose that $f_n$ is the function from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$ whose graph is a straight line joining the points $(0,1)$ and $(\frac{1}{n}, 0)$ together with the straight line joining $(\frac{1}{n},0)$ and $(1,0)$. Then each $f_n$ is a continuous function, as you can see from its  graph.  For each $x \in [0,1]$, the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$ exists and we define $g(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$.  Show that $g(x)$ is not continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is $g(0)$? What is $g(x)$ for any other $x$? Do we have $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x) = g(0)$?

Comment: can you extrapolate? this question is just making me feel dumb.

Comment: For any $n$, we have $f_n(0)= 1$, so $g(0)=1$. But for any other $x$, there is an $N$ so that $1/N<x$, and whenever $n>N$, we have $f_n(x)=0$, so $g(x) =0$. Therefore we must have $$\cases{g(x) =1&$x=0$\\g(x)=0 &$x>0$}$$